# Making a merge sort near identical to pseudocode for homework

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, indexing, mergesort

I have been working on making a merge sort, so far i think everything works except the part where I have to compare the right and left arrays.  help!  (this is for a homework assignment, so it has to be almost identical to this pseudo code:

```
/*MERGESORT(A, p, r)]
    if p < r
        q = (p+r)/2
        MERGESORT(A,p,q)
        MERGESORT(A,q + 1, r)
        MERGE(A,p,q,r)

MERGE(A,p,q,r)
    n1 = q - p + 1
    n2 = r - q
    let L[1...n1 + 1] and R[1...n2 + 1] be new arrays
    for i = 1 to n1
        L[i] = A[p + i - 1]
    for j = 1 to n2
        R[j] = A[q + j]
    L[n1 + 1] = INFINITY
    R[n2 + 1] = INFINITY
    i = 1
    j = 1
    for k = p to r
        if L[i] <= R[j]
            A[k] = L[i]
            i = i + 1
        else
            A[k] = R[j]
            j = j + 1*/
```

these are the merge sort functions Note: ignore the integer type, it does nothing yet.

```
void CensusData::mergeSort(int type) {
    if(type == 0) //STOPPED FOR DEBUGGING
        MERGE_SORT(type, 0, data.size() - 1);
}

void CensusData::MERGE_SORT(int type, int p, int r){
    //int q;
    //cout << "data size " << data.size() << endl;
    std::cout << "MERGE_SORT START ///("<< p << ", " << r << ")" <<std::endl;
    if(p < r)
    {
        int q = (p + r)/2;
        MERGE_SORT(type, p, q);
        MERGE_SORT(type, q + 1, r);
        MERGE(type, p, q ,r);
    }
}

void CensusData::MERGE(int type, int p, int q, int r){
    if(type == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "MERGING WITH: (" << p << ", "<< q <<", " << r<< ")"<< std::endl;
        //int n1;
        //int n2;
        int n1 = q - p + 1;
        int n2 = r - q;
        cout << "N1: " << n1 <<" N2:" << n2 << endl;
        Record* L[n1 + 1];
        Record* R[n2 + 1];
        L[n1 + 1] = NULL;
        R[n2 + 1] = NULL;
        for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        {
            //if (L[i] == NULL)
                //continue;
            cout << "P, I: " << p <<", "<< i<< endl;
            cout << "filling array L: " << data[p + i]->population << endl;
            L[i] = data[p + i];
            cout<< L[i]->population << endl;
        }
        //cout << "J: " << j << endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        {
            //if(R[j] == NULL)
                //continue;
            cout << "filling array R: " << data[q + j + 1]->population<<endl;
            R[j] = data[q + j + 1];
            cout << R[j]->population << endl;
        }
        //THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEMS ARE OCCURING FROM VVVVVVVVVVV
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for(int k = p; k <= r; k++)
        {
            if(L[i]->population < R[j]->population)
            {
                cout << "TRUE" << endl;
                data[k] = L[i];
                i = i + 1;
            }
            else if (L[i]->population > R[j]->population)
            {
                cout << "FALSE" << endl;
                data[k] = R[j];
                j = j + 1;
            }
        }
           /*std::vector<Record*>::iterator it = data.begin();
   while (it != data.end()) {
      std::cout << *(*it)->city << ", "
                << *(*it)->state << ", "
                << (*it)->population << std::endl;
      it++;}*/

    }
}
```

input:::

```
Vina, California, 237
San Francisco, California, 812826
Santa Fe, New Mexico, 68642
```

output:::

```
Vina, California, 237
Santa Fe, New Mexico, 68642

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00445cf7 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/iostream:77
77        static ios_base::Init __ioinit;
```

input example 2:::

```
Vina, California, 237
San Francisco, California, 812826
Santa Fe, New Mexico, 68642
Roseville, California, 1293
New York, New York, 283822
pieland, Conneticut, 283822
```

output from that::::

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004031ae in CensusData::MERGE (this=0x28aa40, type=0, p=0, q=2, r=5)
    at CensusDataSorts.cpp:105
105                 if(L[i]->population < R[j]->population)
```

Answer (score 1):

These statements are wrong (out of bounds array access)

```
   L[n1 + 1] = NULL;
   R[n2 + 1] = NULL;
```

I think that you probably meant

```
   L[n1] = NULL;
   R[n2] = NULL;
```

because in the pseudo code arrays start at 1 but in your code arrays start a zero. I expect that this difference is going to be the cause of most of your issues.

Another probem is that you are using NULL to mean what the pseudo code calls INFINITY but when you do your comparisons you don't check for NULL.

So

```
        if(L[i]->population < R[j]->population)
```

becomes

```
        if ((L[i] != NULL && R[j] != NULL && L[i]->population < R[j]->population) ||
            (L[i] == NULL && R[j] != NULL))
```

similar change for the next if statement

```
        else if ((L[i] != NULL && R[j] != NULL && L[i]->population > R[j]->population) ||
            (L[i] != NULL && R[j] == NULL))
```

Comment: i did that and now the input example 2 outputs::: 237, 1293, 68642, and then seg faults.

Comment: any pointers on how i could implement it in the if and if else statements, i have been staring at thsi code for hours, its really hard to think.

Comment: i added that to the if and changed the if else to just an ELSE, and now nothing is output, and it seg faults over here:  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0040304e in CensusData::MERGE (this=0x28aa40, type=0, p=0, q=1, r=2)
    at CensusDataSorts.cpp:87
87                  cout << "filling array L: " << data[p + i]->population << endl;

Comment: i removed the couts and this is what happens after i added those if and if else things:                                                                                                 Vina, California, 237

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00402935 in CensusData::print (this=0x28aa40) at CensusData.cpp:88
88            std::cout << *(*it)->city << ", "

Comment: note: i am not allowed to change the file it is seg faulting in

Comment: @RyanMann I think you should use a debugger to help you find the problems. Trace throught he code step by step and see where it deviates from what you expected. When you get a crash it's almost always because something went wrong earlier. So use a debugger to track down what that was. This may take a while.

Comment: @RyanMann Another tip. To simplify things try working with a much smaller file. Try sorting a file that has only two Records, if that works then try a file with only three and so on. This will make debugging easier because you're working with a smaller data set.